# Html js Funktion IE undefined

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

im just starting to learn html and cant seem to get my js file running on IE. In firefox this script runs without a problem but on IE the debugger throws me a function undefined error for the alertTest funktion.
Im just trying to call an Alarm when i press a button.
This is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavascriptTest</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="TestJava.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="alertTest()" />
</body>
```

and this would be my TestJava.js file (they are both on the same location on my computer)

```
function alertTest()
{
    window.alert("Alarm");
}
```

I guess this is some simple mistake i made but i cant seem to get it right =/ 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just use alert instead of window.alert?

Comment: Also, adding an onclick attribute to a submit button expects a `true`/`false` response.

Comment: What function is undefined???

Answer (score 0):

It should be enought to use just

```
    alert("Alarm");
```

instead of

```
    window.alert("Alarm")
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the input, i will add a return statement and change  to alert instead of window.alert. I'll respond again after trying

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the suggested solution idea's but still only works for firefox and not on IE. The code so far looks like this now.
    
    
        
            JavascriptTest

```
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return alertTest();" />
</body>
```

and

```
function alertTest()
{
    alert("Alarm");
    return true;
}
```